# How can I remove modem-manager from boot?

Tags: services, modem-manager

I would like to remove  modem-manager service from my boot, how can I do it ?

Comment: Found this question after getting intermittent "SAM-BA operation failed" error using Arduino IDE to flash an Adafruit Feather M0- see https://digistump.com/board/index.php/topic,1163.msg5363.html?PHPSESSID=6b11pdf6b0iqm1snijl7ar8rt4#msg5363 . Executing `systemctl status ModemManager.service` shows that modem-manager is the culprit: `Could not grab port (tty/ttyACM0): 'Cannot add port 'tty/ttyACM0', unhandled serial type'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This it looks to work fine:

```
sudo mv /usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.ModemManager.service /usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.ModemManager.service.disabled
```

Instead this doesn't work ( don't know y ):

```
"echo manual | sudo tee -a /etc/init/modemmanager.override"
```

Comment: As of `ubuntu 14.04` and `Linux Mint 17.3`, it is `ModemManager1`; I'm now used to do also `sudo ugo-x /usr/sbin/ModemManager`.

Answer (score 31):

```
systemctl disable ModemManager.service
systemctl stop ModemManager.service
```

This worked to disable UML-295 modem from being managed by ModemManger which in turn enabled web-control via http://mbb.vzw.com on CentOS 7.

Check after disabling via:

```
systemctl list-dependencies multi-user.target | grep Modem
```

Comment: working for Ubuntu 16.04. Deactivates for me most of my "SetLineState" on my USB-Trace.

Comment: Short Answer: `sudo systemctl disable ModemManager`

Answer (score 10):

The simplest way is to:

```
sudo apt-get purge modemmanager
```

Works fine in 12.04 LTS. Nothing in my system had dependencies on modemmanager.

Or you could search for "modemmanager" in the Ubuntu Software Center and remove it from there (the title is "D-Bus service for managing modems").

Comment: you are right but does you need it for connection with mobile phone  ?

Comment: @Postadelmaga: Well, I guess it depends how your software connects to your phone. If you find you do need it after all, you can always re-install it with `sudo apt-get install modemmanager`, no?

Comment: you are right, but what happen if I have no internet connection in that moment ( and y should I use my phone to navigate if I have internet :)
What I'm looking for is a way to not load it every boot, but still be able to run it if I need it ....

Answer (score 0):

1. If it is SysV init style symbolic links

   ```
   update-rc.d [-n] [-f] base_name remove
   ```
2. If it is per user (X11 session), check the following folders and remote corresponding files:

   ```
   ~/.config/autostart    
   /etc/xdg/autostart
   ```

Comment: thank u but it is not a SysV init ... it is a upstart service, see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

I found this had only a deleterious function when I tried the experimental version in Debian Sid and it failed to find my modem at all. That nearly doubled my speed and drops and failures became rare. I will probably remove it but for the time I want it to suspend function.

In `/etc/init.d` I stored this file:

```
#!/bin/sh
# NOMODEMMANAGER.sh DHM, Feb'19
# The ModemManager appears to slow down and interfere with the internet on my Dell laptop.
ModemManager --no-auto-scan
```