# How find out who is using my virtual commport over usb

Tags: serial-port

Sometimes when I am using a VCP (/dev/ttyACM0) someone is trying to talk with my device sending "ATE1 E0ATE1 E0ATE1" commands. How to catch who is doing this? 
Is it possible that the "program" that sends these commands to be part of the linux drivers? Or it is just some smart application program that is looking for newly attached devices?
I'm getting this sequence when I'm dealing with different terminal programs, so I think that this sequence doesn't come from them - picocom and folie.

Comment: `sudo lsof /dev/ttyACM0` will show you every process that has the device open.

Answer (score 0):

These look like Hayes modem commands. You have some app or driver trying to initialize a modem device.

The E command determines whether characters are echoed to the DTE from the modem when it is command state. Some computers and terminals do not send the characters you type to the screen; they only transmit them to the remote system through the serial port. In this case, if Command State Character Echo were not enabled by the modem, you would be unable to see what you type. If the DTE does echo the characters you type in command state, and this function is enabled in the modem, each character typed will appear twice.

```
E0     Command state character echo disabled.
E1     Command state character echo enabled.
```

source: http://www.messagestick.net/modem/Hayes_Ch1-1.html

Answer (score 0):

Just went through this as well. minicom wouldn't stop printing these Hayes AT commands.
remove or disable ModemManager was the solution for me.

[How can I remove modem-manager from boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/216114/how-can-i-remove-modem-manager-from-boot)